# Trying to us str.contains and boolean mask but for only for a single value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble coming up with a good solution for isolating rows with the same unique ID that only contain instances of a specific value, while dropping all rows with a shared unique ID if they contain any other values. (sorry if this isnt clear, but I have example df's below)

This is the logic that I have for a str.contains and boolean mask and I'm thinking of using something similar...

df[df['ID'].isin(df.loc[df1.Yurrr.str.contains('Bodega'), 'ID'].unique())]

Example df:

```
   ID      %       Yurrr
    abc123  0.833   Bodega
    abc123  0.87    Bodega
    abc123  0.867   Bodega
    abc123  0.812   Bodega
    lmn789  0.837   Beck's
    lmn789  0.856   Chopped Cheese
    lmn789  0.813   Bodega
    lmn789  0.812   Beck's
    xyz456  0.111   Cardi B
    xyz456  0.222   Cardi B
    xyz456  0.333   Bodega
    xyz456  0.444   Bodega
```

Output df:

```
    ID      %       Yurrr
    abc123  0.833   Bodega
    abc123  0.87    Bodega
    abc123  0.867   Bodega
    abc123  0.812   Bodega
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
df[df.groupby('ID')['Yurrr'].transform(lambda x: x.str.contains('Bodega').all())]
```

OR

```
df[df.Yurrr.str.contains('Bodega').groupby(df['ID']).transform(all)]
```

Output:

```
       ID      %   Yurrr
0  abc123  0.833  Bodega
1  abc123  0.870  Bodega
2  abc123  0.867  Bodega
3  abc123  0.812  Bodega
```

Comment: @KirklandShawty You're welcome.   Happy coding!  Would you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) this solution?